# In docker, can I bind-mount a folder to multiple containers, multiple times?

Tags: docker

In my `docker-compose.yml` I have two services (`mariadb` and `symmetricds`) with bind-mounts to `mnt` folder, specific container directories.

Now, from `toolbox` container **I'd like to access all the `mnt` folder for backup purposes**. Can I bind-mount `mnt` to container `/data/mnt`... or I will run into troubles?

```
version: '3'

services:
    mariadb:
         volumes:
            - ./mnt/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d:/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d
            - ./mnt/var/log/mysql:/var/log/mysql
        # ....

    symmetricds:
        volumes:
            - ./mnt/opt/symmetric-ds/engines:/opt/symmetric-ds/engines
            - ./mnt/var/log/symmetric-ds:/opt/symmetric-ds/logs
        # ...

    toolbox:
        volumes:
            - ./mnt/etc/periodic:/etc/periodic
            - ./mnt:/data/mnt:ro # can I do this?
        # ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can.

Docker does not stop you from using the same volume in two containers. In fact, this is the way to share data between containers.

Just be careful not to update the same files in two containers, as it might cause data-consistency issues

Comment: This is great. So, isn't a bad practice to mount multiple containers data to folders in `/mnt` (host folder)... and then, mount the entire `/mnt` to another container, for doing a backup?

Comment: Looks good to me. Every service has a singular responsibility while being unaware of the underlying directory structure. Only the backup container is aware of the directory structure

Comment: Also, you can mount the `/mnt` folder in backup container in read-only mode, by adding `:ro` to mount  directive